# How can we celebrate the release of 3.1

Tags: discussion

Streamers on the site?  A JavaScript fireworks script?

What can we do to show our support and appreciation of [the 180 developers who contributed](http://wordpress.org/news/2011/02/threeone/) to this thing we all love and give this site meaning?

Comment: How many of those 180 contributors have an account on WPSE?

Comment: More and more all the time, but I'd wager about half off the top of my head (based on who I interact with both here and elsewhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps we can all celebrate by upgrading to the latest version.

*(goes to update 3 sites, as I didn't know this was out..)*

Comment: I've added a system note to the main site to help raise awareness :-)  Don't worry, the word is just now getting around ... I just happened to be sitting around waiting for the official announcement.

Comment: @EAMann: The notification sprites ["leak" on the iPhone](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7057637/WPSE%20notification%20error.jpg).

Comment: @Jan More evidence that we should all switch to Android?  Or perhaps the notification is just too long ... I've shortened it ... let me know if that helped.

Comment: @EAMann: It's better now, thanks. (It was a minor issue of course.) I first thought it wouldn't be needed to place this notice at the top of the site because everyone will see it in their admin console, but then I saw Jeff's message. And it would be weird to do nothing, as if this is not an important release.

Answer (score 1):

We have [some questions about new features in 3.1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=3.1), maybe we could give them some prominence via a header message? We don't have (or shouldn't have) a tag for this version, but maybe the new features have tags? I can only think of [admin-bar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/admin-bar).

Comment: `<admin-bar>` ... `<post-format>` ... `<taxonomy-query>` ...